# How to use a different Jenkins plugin version on hpi:run?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to use `mvn hpi:run -Djetty.port=8090` to work on a plugin for Jenkins, but I want to use the latest version.  When my Jenkins starts up, it's always "ver. 1.625.3".

How can I make it start up using 2.x?  I tried setting a version in the pom.xml but it didn't work.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.11</version>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial#Plugintutorial-pom.xml.

Either run Maven with `mvn hpi:run -Djetty.port=8090 -Djenkins.version=1.625.3` or add the following snippet to your POM:

```
<properties>
  <jenkins.version>1.625.3</jenkins.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to work.  I tried mvn hpi:run -Djetty.port=8090 -Djenkins.version=2.23 because I want to use a newer version but it still uses version 1.630.  Any ideas?

Comment: It works for me. I tested this with the [Credentials Binding Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin) and `mvn hpi:run -Djetty.port=8090 -Djenkins.version=2.23 -Denforcer.skip`. Must be a problem in your POM. Can you post a link to your POM?

Comment: I tried again and something must have been wrong somewhere.  It works now.  Thanks!